# A bourne shell program that echos values in a file

Tags: bash, shell

Looking for a bourne shell program that accepts a file as a positional parameter and echos the values in the file to output in single column.

file contains:
aikman,troy reynolds,burt smith,john jones,colin

currently i have this but not working

```
#!/bin/sh 
if [ $# != 1 ] 
then 
echo usage: $0 FILE_NAME 
exit 1 
fi 

cat $1
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Define "value" in the input file. Whitespace-separate values on each line?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want to read a file, removing all newlines and replacing them with commas.
If that is the case, this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [ $# != 1 ]
then
        echo usage: $0 FILE_NAME
        exit 1
fi

sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' $1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# != 1 ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 FILE_NAME"
    exit 1
fi

awk -F, -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' "$1"
```

Example usage:

```
sh script.sh file
```

Where file contains

```
aikman,troy reynolds,burt smith,john jones,colin
```

Output:

```
aikman
troy reynolds
burt smith
john jones
colin
```

Answer (score 0):

From the file

```
aikman,troy reynolds,burt smith,john jones,colin
```

the

```
grep -oP '\S+' filename
```

produces

```
aikman,troy
reynolds,burt
smith,john
jones,colin
```

and the

```
grep -oP '\w+' filename
```

produces

```
aikman
troy
reynolds
burt
smith
john
jones
colin
```

and the

```
grep -oP '[^,]+' filename
```

produces

```
aikman
troy reynolds
burt smith
john jones
colin
```

full script:

```
case $# in
1) grep -oP '[^,]+' "$1" ;;
*) echo "Usage: $0 filename";exit 1 ;;
esac
```

better (accept many filenames)

```
for file
do
    grep -oP '\S+' "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the space-separated values each on a separate line,

```
tr ' ' '\n' <file
```

will do that.

Not all dialects of `tr` understand the symbol `\n` to mean newline; try with `\012` or a literal newline:

```
tr ' ' '
' <file
```

(Yes, that's a literal newline between the second pair of single quotes.)

A more sustainable solution is to switch the data file to have one name per line instead, or otherwise replace it with something less wacky.

Answer (score 0):

You can print each field on a separate line with Awk:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' "$1"
```

Output:

```
aikman,troy
reynolds,burt
smith,john
jones,colin
```